# Can this be considered legally a fraud from a United Nations organization?

Tags: fraud

I came across a job advertisement few weeks ago in Stackoverflow:

https://stackoverflow.com/jobs/305935/application-architect-net-c-sharp-unops?so=i&pg=1&offset=0&l=thailand&u=Km&d=20

As you can see, the job was posted somewhen in January.

Now, if you click on the "apply" button, you end up in their site where you could theoretically apply. However you cannot apply because the "closing" date is set to be in November. So this job advertisement is like that since a month ago, and this has not changed.

It means, the job advertisement is there already a month but none could apply, i.e. they have 0 applicants. Because the job was posted only in January 2020 but the closing date is set to November 2019. Is technically impossible anyone could apply.

In addition to that, if you click in the link "Report fraud", the link is no working.

Is there any way to legally demonstrate that this is a fraud? i.e. that they intentionally disallow any applicants so that they can assign the position to someone they know personally? i.e. relatives, friends etc, but the salary is being paid with the founding of United Nations, that turn out to be paid from the taxes of all citizens that live in United Nations countries?

Answer (score 4):

> Is there any way to legally demonstrate that this is a fraud?

That is quite difficult and unlikely. The nonsense in the deadline could be the result of sloppy job by whoever drafted the advertisement rather than an intentional blocking of candidates.

Proving that there was fraud, conflict of interests, or akin misconduct, would require auditing the department which conducts the recruitment and/or the purchasing. But an applicant would hardly be allowed to scrutinize the department's records to ascertain whether or not the department incurred fraud.

The most you can to is to report the suspected misconduct with the UN department in charge of compliance and/or contact your country's UN delegation to address the issue.

That being said, it is most likely that the issue stems from sloppiness in the dates or the mistaken posting of a position does not exist and which is not contemplated in the near future. When commercial or official entities indulge in --or intend to engage in-- fraudulent practices, they typically resort to discreet methods precisely to avoid getting busted.

Comment: What you said makes sense except one thing. Because none can apply... did none realised that they have published an advertisement, that is really expensive in Stackoverflow, but they get no applicants for a month now? i.e. none wonders why none sent an application to a nice job? still they are spending a huge amount of money in this ad.

So to me it looks like the people who posted this ad know what is going on.

Comment: @Askingtomanyquestions You might be surprised how bureaucratic and dumb are some employees at institutions with huge budgets, not to mention the high number of simultaneous screening processes and job openings going on at an entity of that size. And if it is about a position that does not exists and is not even contemplated for the near future, nobody will notice that the advertisement has received zero applications.

Comment: Interesting. :(